# Toggling audio on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, click

please look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/yLdkj/1/

The above fiddle shows three bars that on hover play audios. How do I change this so the music plays and pauses on click instead. Also if one audio is playing and another is clicked how can the already playing song pause?

```
 $("#one").mouseenter(function () {
 $('#sound-1').get(0).play();
 });
$("#one").mouseleave(function () {
$('#sound-1').get(0).pause();
});
$("#two").mouseenter(function () {
$('#sound-2').get(0).play();
});
$("#two").mouseleave(function () {
$('#sound-2').get(0).pause();
});
$("#three").mouseenter(function () {
$('#sound-3').get(0).play();
});
$("#three").mouseleave(function () {
$('#sound-3').get(0).pause();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<div id="sound-bars">
    <div id="one" class="bars" data-target="#sound-1"></div>
    <div id="two" class="bars" data-target="#sound-2"></div>
    <div id="three" class="bars" data-target="#sound-3"></div>
</div>
<audio id="sound-1" class="sound">
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.mp3"></source>
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.oggvorbis.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't compatible.
</audio>
<audio id="sound-2" class="sound">
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/you did not listen .mp3"></source>
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/you did not listen .oggvorbis.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't compatible.
</audio>
<audio id="sound-3" class="sound">
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/can you hear me .mp3"></source>
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/can you hear me .oggvorbis.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't compatible.
</audio>
```

then

```
var $sounds = $('.sound'),
    $bars = $('#sound-bars .bars');
$bars.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $target = $($this.data('target')),
        target = $target[0];
    $bars.not(this).removeClass('playing');
    $sounds.not($target).each(function () {
        this.pause();
    });

    $this.toggleClass('playing');
    if ($this.hasClass('playing')) {
        target.play();
    } else {
        target.pause();
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4HQjM/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check pause all audio on click of a div, then just play the associated audio. You can tidy up the code a bit too:

**jQuery:**

```
$(".playbtn").click(function() {
    // Pause all audio
    $("audio").each(function(index, elem) {
        elem.pause();
    });
    // Grab the associated sound ID
    var soundId = $(this).data("soundid");
    // Play the audio
    $("#sound-"+soundId)[0].play();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="playbtn" data-soundid="1">Play #1</div>
<div class="playbtn" data-soundid="2">Play #2</div>
<div class="playbtn" data-soundid="3">Play #3</div>
<div class="playbtn" data-soundid="4">Play #4</div>

<audio id="sound-1">
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.mp3"></source>
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.oggvorbis.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't compatible.
</audio>
<audio id="sound-2">
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.mp3"></source>
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.oggvorbis.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't compatible.
</audio>
<audio id="sound-3">
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.mp3"></source>
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.oggvorbis.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't compatible.
</audio>
<audio id="sound-4">
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.mp3"></source>
    <source src="http://angelaandtom.co.uk/lib/audio/Intro-.oggvorbis.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't compatible.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#one").click(function () {
  pauseAll();
    $('#sound-1').get(0).play();
});

$("#two").click(function () {
pauseAll();         
    $('#sound-2').get(0).play();
});

$("#three").click(function () {
      pauseAll();
    $('#sound-3').get(0).play();
});
function pauseAll(){
  $("audio").each(function (){
        this.pause();
    });
}
```

This works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YR2Yd/).

Comment: your links seems to go back to my original fiddle?

Comment: thanks but can it also pause when clicking in the same bar? for example click on bar one, music plays, click on same bar it pauses?

Comment: No. It will first pause all, but then play the current. But you will not get to feel if it was really paused.
You can see for yourself http://jsfiddle.net/YR2Yd/


Updated the link in the answer also.